# ios ionic stuck on splashscreen, with no error displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I want to run an Ionic App on IOS 9+

When i manage to compile and run on my ios device, the application start, and then stay stuck to splashscreen.

I've been able to remove the "Unexpected call to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" message, and the app still stuck on the splashscreen, so i guess it's not related. 
I also guess that my app is starting, because it ask me to allow notifications.

I tried a lot of tips found on internet, none of them work, so i am a bit confused now.

Here's the log i found interesting.

> 2019-10-09 17:36:42.944700+0200 app[578:73013] Could not signal
>   service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified
>   service
>
> 2019-10-09 17:36:45.705566+0200 app[578:73013] CDVWKWebViewEngine will
>   reload WKWebView if required on resume
>
> 2019-10-09 17:36:45.975980+0200 app[578:73013] CDVPlugin class
>   WKWebViewXHRFix (pluginName: wkwebviewxhrfix) does not exist
>
> 2019-10-09 17:36:46.414226+0200 app[578:73013] Unexpected call to
>   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, ignoring: 
>   2019-10-09 17:36:47.471808+0200 app[578:73155] 4.13.0 -
>   [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications
>   proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If
>   you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add
>   "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to
>   NO. Follow the instructions at: XXX 2019-10-09 17:36:47.496357+0200
>   app[578:73157] 4.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase
>   Analytics v.40200000 started 2019-10-09 17:36:47.499395+0200
>   app[578:73157] 4.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable
>   debug logging set the following application argument:
>   -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled  2019-10-09 17:36:51.199418+0200 app[578:73013] InstanceID token: xxx